# Accepting Connections asynchronous with a Proxy Server

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous

When I want to open a new Thread for every Incoming Request. Is this good way to do it? Will there be a new Thread with every accepted Request? The BeginReceive Method called in the end of this piece of code Works asynchronous aswell.

```
public void Listen(IPEndPoint EndPoint)
    {
        try
        {
            ListeningSocket.Bind(EndPoint);
            ListeningSocket.Listen(BACKLOG);
            BeginAccept();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message + "\nfrom Source: " + e.Source + "\nand Stack Trace: " + e.StackTrace);
        }
    }

    public void BeginAccept()
    {
        try
        {
            ListeningSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(Accept_Callback), new ServerSocket());
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Listening Socket Error:" + e.ErrorCode);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Listening Socket has been closed");
        }
    }


    private void Accept_Callback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        BeginAccept();
        try
        {
            if (asyncResult.AsyncState != null)
            {
                ServerSocket serverSocket = asyncResult.AsyncState as ServerSocket;
                if ((serverSocket.CommunicationSocket = ListeningSocket.EndAccept(asyncResult)) != null)
                {

                    BeginReceive(serverSocket);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Listening Socket Error:" + e.ErrorCode);
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The Listening Socket has been closed");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach uses threads from a ThreadPool which is a good thing. While waiting for a new client to be accepted or for data to arrive no threads are used, so your code will not span 1000 threads when you have 1000 clients connected.

Just when data arrives on one socket, one free thread will be taken from the tread pool and will process your callback. When your method finishes, the thread will be returned to the pool to be available for the next data arrival or client connection.

Comment: Ok, in Addition, this approach will work fine? As far as I understood, the asynchronous approach has some performance advantages compared to a non-System-Threadpool.

Comment: Yes, its fine. The advantages are: You are just using threads when there is some work to do, when no data arrives and no new client connects, your app is idle.